# Build error of C# reference of name space in two projects in VS 2013 win 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, reference, namespaces

I am doing C# programming on Visual Studio 2013 win 7.

In project 1 I have:

```
using test.name.abc;  // error: type or namespace "test" cannot be found.  
public class testName2 : testName1  // build error here 
{
    public int id;
}
```

And in project 2:

```
 namespace test.name.abc
 {
     public class testName1
     {
        public int dd;
     }

  }
```

I have added reference of dll file generated from project2 in project1. I also made the build dependence as project1 depends on project2.

But, I always got build error of

> The type or namespace name 'testName1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `test.name.123` is **not** a valid identifier for a namespace!

Comment: @Selman22, why ? no build error in project2. thx !

Comment: where is project2.dll located?

Comment: @terrybozzio, all dll files are located in myProject\bin\debug.

Comment: For the people who vote it down, please give a reason. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces and type names connot begin with a numeric character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691136(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is that the case here. `test.name.123` does not begin with a numeric character.

Comment: works fine for me with the new name. try cleaning your solution, rebuilding project 2 and then removing and re-adding the project reference